# Kendo UI: k-input's result is different for text and password

Tags: html, kendo-ui

I am new to use Kendo UI. I try k-input in  tag for "text"  and "Password" . But the style is different. how to make both look alike?

```
<input type="text" name="uname" class="k-input"/><br><br>
<input type="password" name="pwd" class="k-input"/><br><br>
```

[Output of this code : here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTQmU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kendo UI uses data attributes to achieve that purpose. You can create your password field like that:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="*" id="Password" name="Password" type="password" class="k-textbox" />
```

Demo here:
http://dojo.telerik.com/aZEpE